# Specifying colClasses in read.table using the class function

Tags: r, read.table

Is there a way to use `read.table()` to read all or part of the file in, use the class function to get the column types, modify the column types, and then re-read the file?

Basically I have columns which are zero padded integers that I like to treat as strings.  If I let `read.table()` just do its thing it of course assumes these are numbers and strips off the leading zeros and makes the column type integer.  Thing is I have a fair number of columns so while I can create a character vector specifying each one I only want to change a couple from what R's best guess is.  What I'd like to do is read the first few lines:

```
myTable <- read.table("//myFile.txt", sep="\t", quote="\"", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, nrows = 5)
```

Then get the column classes:

```
colTypes <- sapply(myTable, class)
```

Change a couple of column types i.e.:

```
colTypes[1] <- "character"
```

And then re-read the file in using the modified column types:

```
myTable <- read.table("//myFile.txt", sep="\t", quote="\"", colClasses=colTypes, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, nrows = 5)
```

While this seems like an infinitely reasonable thing to do, and `colTypes = c("character")` works fine, when I actually try it I get a:

```
scan() expected 'an integer', got '"000001"'
```

`class(colTypes)` and `class(c("character"))` both return `"character"` so what's the problem?

Comment: If you have `N` columns, and want to force only the 3rd and 7th to be character, for example, probably something like `col_classes <- rep(NA, N); col_classes[c(3, 7)] <- "character"`, which you would then pass as the `colClasses` argument. From the help file, `[Re: colClasses]: "... Possible values are NA (the default, when type.convert is used) ..."`

Answer (score 0):

You use `read.table`s `colClasses =` argument to specify the columns you want classified as `character`s. For example:

```
txt <- 
"var1, var2, var3
 0001, 0002, 1
 0003, 0004, 2"
df <- 
read.table(
    text = txt,
    sep = ",",
    header = TRUE,
    colClasses = "character") ## read all as characters
df    
df2 <- 
read.table(
    text = txt, 
    sep = ",",
    header = TRUE,
    colClasses = c("character", "character", "double")) ## the third column is numeric 
df2
```

[updated...] or, you could set and re-set `colClasses` with a vector...

```
df <- 
read.table(
    text = txt, 
    sep = ",",
    header = TRUE)
df

## they're all currently read as integer
myColClasses <-   
sapply(df, class)

## create a vector of column names for zero padded variable
zero_padded <-    
c("var1", "var2")

## if a name is in zero_padded, return "character", else leave it be
myColClasses <-   
ifelse(names(myColClasses) %in% zero_padded, 
       "character", 
       myColClasses)

## read in with colClasses set to myColClasses
df2 <- 
read.table(
    text = txt, 
    sep = ",",
    colClasses = myColClasses,
    header = TRUE)
df2
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to shorthand that.  In my real problem I've got a couple hundred columns and I'm happy with most of R's default column types so seems wildly long winded to have to specify the entire thing when I only want to change a couple.

Comment: I suspect it's the always annoying yet rarely useful row names business but row names isn't an actual column so I can't drop it.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Hopefully, I addressed better with the edited answer. Not sure it's efficient, but it might suit your needs.

Comment: Works like a charm and using the column name is probably a better idea than the index.